# The location of the main menu items

Tags: windows, delphi, menuitem

The "Help" menu item in the Total commander is right-aligned. How is it done?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, vibrations from another millenium ;). It is doable, as follows, but I don't really see any advantage.

```
procedure TForm33.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ModifyMenu(MainMenu1.Handle,
             MainMenu1.Items.Count -1,
             MF_BYPOSITION or MF_RIGHTJUSTIFY, // MF_HELP = MF_RIGHTJUSTIFY = $4000
             MainMenu1.Items[MainMenu1.Items.Count-1].Command,
             '&Help' );
end;
```

[image]

You may want to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-modifymenua) and consider the following note:

> Note  The ModifyMenu function has been superseded by the SetMenuItemInfo function. You can still use ModifyMenu, however, if you do not need any of the extended features of SetMenuItemInfo.

---

Edit: In a comment you linked to an image where the "Help" item had been painted on the gradient menu bar with a non-gradient white background. Based on your image, I believe you are using `Windows 7`, so I fired up an old W7 machine and tested the same code with Delphi XE7 and the result is as follows:

[image]

I really don't know how I could possibly help you further, if you can't help me reproduce the problem.

---

Edit2: Thanks to comment by Remy Lebeau I made a correction to the fourth parameter. It was a real blunder from my side not to update that code from my old repositories.

The undocumented `MF_HELP` has the same value as the also undocumented `MF_RIGHTJUSTIFY` ( both are $4000 ). The latter indicates better the purpose, so I changed to that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately I get the following: [link](https://imgur.com/a/w6dwPyn)

Comment: So, which OS version do you have? Do you have any "visual theme addons" installed? Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 and Lazarus 1.6.4. I think this function should not depend on the development environment. Because this is a pure API function.

Comment: @Николай Generally I would agree with you, but still, the only difference now is the dev env. As you did not mention `Lazarus` in your question, and I have already answered how to do it in Delphi, I suggest that you post a new question in line with "Why is there a difference in how Delphi and Lazarus paints right aligned menu items?" You are free to use my W7 picture as a reference, if you like. Please also take in consideration that I have in fact answered the question you asked, with the conditions you presented.

Comment: @TomBrunberg `MF_HELP` is not documented as a valid flag for use in `ModifyMenu()`, even if it "works". Also, you are setting the `uIDNewItem` parameter of `ModifyMenu()` to `0`, which will render the modified menu item unresponsive to user input. You need to preserve the existing ID, eg change `0` to `MainMenu1.Items[MainMenu1.Items.Count-1].Command` instead. The "correct" solution to right-aligning a menu item is to use `SetMenuItemInfo()` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Remy for your comment. I edited my answer. It was a real blunder not to fill in the fourth parameter correctly.

Comment: @TomBrunberg `MF_RIGHTJUSTIFY` is not an official flag defined by Microsoft.  I would strongly suggest simply not using `ModifyMenu()` or this task at all, you are invoking *undocumented behavior*.  The `MFT_RIGHTJUSTIFY` flag of `SetMenuItemInfo()` is official and documented by Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

In Delphi, the VCL's [`TMenuItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem) does not natively support setting its justification, however you can use the Win32 API [`SetMenuItemInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuiteminfow) function to modify a menu item at runtime to give it the `MFT_RIGHTJUSTIFY` flag, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., Windows;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  info: TMenuItemInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@info, sizeof(info));
  info.cbSize := sizeof(info);
  info.fMask := MIIM_FTYPE;

  GetMenuItemInfo(Help1.Parent.Handle, Help1.Command, False, info);
  // or: GetMenuItemInfo(Help1.Parent.Handle, Help1.MenuIndex, True, info);

  info.fType := info.fType or MFT_RIGHTJUSTIFY;

  SetMenuItemInfo(Help1.Parent.Handle, Help1.Command, False, info);
  // or: SetMenuItemInfo(Help1.Parent.Handle, Help1.MenuIndex, True, info);
end;
```

[image]

In FreePascal/Lazarus, the LCL's [`TMenuItem`](https://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.io/docs/lcl/menus/tmenuitem.html) has a published [`RightJustify`](https://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.io/docs/lcl/menus/tmenuitem.rightjustify.html) property that you can set to `True`.